# How do I also get the sum of a child table in web api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

This is my Order model:

```
    public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int? Active { get; set; }
    public int? CreditorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Creditor Creditor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

This is my OrderItem model:

```
    public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public int ItemQty { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int ItemTaxGroup { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemTotalTax { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemTotalPrice { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

This is my current controller query:

```
return db.Orders.Where(order => order.Active == 1);
```

This returns the following json:

```
{"OrderID":3,"OrderDate":"2014-11-26T00:00:00","OrderStatus":"Draft"},
{"OrderID":4,"OrderDate":"2014-11-26T00:00:00","OrderStatus":"Draft"},
{"OrderID":5,"OrderDate":"2014-11-26T00:00:00","OrderStatus":"Draft"}
```

Using SQL this is what I need it to return (the sum of the related OrderItems):

```
SELECT PT.*, (SELECT SUM([ItemTotalPrice]) FROM [OrderItems] AS CT WHERE CT.OrderID = PT.OrderID) AS OrderTotal
FROM [Orders] AS PT
WHERE PT.Active = 1
```

This is what I need it to return in json:

```
{"OrderID":3,"OrderDate":"2014-11-26T00:00:00","OrderStatus":"Draft","OrderTotal":189.95},
{"OrderID":4,"OrderDate":"2014-11-26T00:00:00","OrderStatus":"Draft","OrderTotal":88.0},
{"OrderID":5,"OrderDate":"2014-11-26T00:00:00","OrderStatus":"Draft","OrderTotal":0.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a new select for your items and i'm not sure how your setup is, but you will probably want to create a new model/viewmodel to hold your data in. Something like this

```
public class OrderViewModel {
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}
    public string OrderStatus {get; set;}
    public decimal OrderTotal {get; set;}
}
```

Then your select will look something along these lines,

```
var orders = (from o in Orders
                where o.Active == 1
                select new OrderViewModel   
                            { OrderId = o.OrderId,
                              OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                              OrderStatus = o.OrderStatus,
                              OrderTotal = o.OrderItems.Sum(oi => oi.ItemTotalPrice)
                            });
```